# Switching to webview fail in Android on Mac OS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, android, appium

I have a problem while switching from native view to webview in Android while testing on MAC OS. But the same scripts works fine in windows. In Mac it gives chrome not reachable as a webdriver exception or some times session not found exception. I'm using Appium with Eclipse in Mac. I tried replacing different version of chromedriver but none of them worked. Any solution for this!

Thanks

Comment: please post the error

Answer (score 0):

I am **using same environment** as you described and working fine. Dinesh give a try:

```
Set<String> contextNames = ad.getContextHandles();      
System.out.println("Context Names:"+contextNames.toString());

String lastestContextView = (String) contextNames.toArray()[contextNames.size()-1];

if (lastestContextView.contains("WEBVIEW_"))
{
    ad.context(lastestContextView);
    System.out.println("Latest Context Name"+lastestContextView);
}                   
Thread.sleep(5000);
ad.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Comment: where should I use this? For native switch or webview ?

Comment: Webview  to Native man,Simple